# Grails UrlMapping with hypenated id returns 404

Tags: grails, url-mapping

I've changed the default UrlMapping from

```
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }
```

to

```
    "/$controller/$action(-$id)??(.$format)?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }
```

however then I navigate to `item/item-1` I get a page not found response. While actions such as `item/items` seem to work normally. Is it not possible to have a hyphen separated id?

Comment: Try this one: "/$controller/$action-$id??(.$format)?"

Comment: @Koloritnij that triggers an action with "item-1" but refuses to trigger with "items". Also I wasn't able to extract the id with params.id